# Why isn't an injection defined with an iff?

Tags: functions, definition

Suppose that $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a function.

Then an injection can be defined as:

$$\forall x_1,x_2 \in X, f(x_1) = f(x_2) \Rightarrow x_1=x_2$$

Why isn't it defined instead as follows?

$$\forall x_1,x_2 \in X, f(x_1) = f(x_2) \Leftrightarrow x_1=x_2$$

I think the above statement also captures the situation described by the definition of an injection in words, which is:

> If no element of $Y$ is assigned to more than one elementof $X$, i.e. the function takes a different value for each point of the domain.

I can see that the definition is missing the phrase "if and only if". So is that the only reason we don't write "$\Leftrightarrow$"?

Comment: It could be defined like that, the but the other direction is always true by definition of function.

Comment: Your question has been answered adequately. Here an alternative definition: $f$ is injective if it is left-cancellable; i.e. $f\circ g=f\circ h$ implies that $g=h$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76186/definition-of-injective-function?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that the fact that $f$ is a function implies that $x_1=x_2\implies f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

So if you say that $f$ is an injective function, then $\leftarrow$ part is already true. So in order to save ourselves trivialities, we only state the $\implies$ part, and then when you want to prove that $f$ is injective you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Here is another definition. $$(\forall x_1,x_2 \in X, f(x_1) = f(x_2) \Leftrightarrow x_1=x_2) \wedge (1+1 = 2)$$

Comment: What's your point?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The point, I believe, is to show the OP that one can include a bunch of needless trivialities in the definitions.

Comment: @GitGud: I see. Yes, that is a point. But it seems to interprets the question as being facetious, rather than an actual question of a newbie.

Comment: @AsafKaragila We're seeing things differently. I think user147887 wanted to complement your answer with a more extreme example of the needlessness of including unnecessary stuff in definitions.

Comment: I didn't mean to seem facetious, I just wanted to emphasize that the reason it is not "if and only if" is not because it is wrong but because it is unnecessary.

Comment: @user147887: I see. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the definition you propose are equivalent if $f$ is function. [By definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition) if $f$ is a function, $x_1=x_2$ implies $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

Comment: @GitGud Yeah sorry, it was not very well expressed.

Comment: No need to apologize. I removed my comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you suppose $f$ as a function, than the converse of your implication is not necessary. The implication $x_1=x_2 \implies f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ tells us only that f is a function!

Comment: "The implication $x_1=x_2 \implies f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ tells us only that $f$ is a function!" This implication already assumes $f$ is a function, other wise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly your comment. Are you saying that if we assume $f$ to be a function, than the implication is redundant?

Comment: I mean that $x_1=x_2 \implies f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ is something that only makes sense if $f$ is already known to be a function. Well, if $f$ is already known to be a function, you don't need $x_1=x_2 \implies f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ to claim that $f$ is a function. And if it is not known whether $f$ is a function or not, then $x_1=x_2 \implies f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ is a meaningless string of symbols.

Comment: If $f$ is a relation that we do not know if it is a function or not, than we test it. If the relation $f$ fulfill that condition, than it is a function!

So, I think you are a bit wrong!

Comment: No, if $f$ is a binary relation, you can't write $f(x)$ prior  to proving that that binary relation is a function.

Comment: Why not? f(x) may be a set of elements!

Comment: @emin Why not? Well it is simply not practicized. You can do it, but you're quite lonely then.

Comment: @drhab And even then it is likely that $f(x)$ will be getting two different meanings when $f$ happens to be a function.

Comment: @drhab, actually Emin is correct. The notation $f(x)$ for a relation $f$ is very commonly used to denote the set of all elements related to $x$, or even in many circumstances just _one_ possible element related to $x$. For instance, this is common when working with canonical relations in symplectic geometry or mathematical physics.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez The standard notation for that would be $f[\{x\}]$. I reiterate, when $f$ happens to be a function, if you interpret $f(x)$ as you suggest, you'll be getting $f(x)=\{a\}$ and $f(x)=a$, for some $a$. And to be perfectly honest, the fact that geometers and physicists use that notation, only supports my claim that it is incorrect since they tend to abuse notations.

Comment: @GitGud, it is certainly an abuse of notation, but whether or not it is "good" notation is irrelevant. It was claimed above that "it is simply not practiced. You can do it, but you're quite lonely then", and this is flatly untrue.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez I never saw it used.  That doesn't say everything, but was the inspiration for my comment (don't take it too heavy). In my view Git Gud is correct in his critics here.